# How to set ListExperienceOptions with PnP-Poweshell

Tags: pnp, pnp-powershell

How do I set the ListExperienceOptions of a list to ClassicExperience using the PnP-Powershell? 
I have tried this

```
# Create the list to hold work Types 
New-PNPList -Title "Work Types" -Url "WorkTypes" -Template GenericList -EnableVersioning -OnQuickLaunch -OutVariable $WorkTypesList 
$WorkTypesList.ListExperienceOptions = 2

SWorkTypesList.Update()

$WorkTypesListID = $WorkTypesList.Id
```

but it just trashes my library. Do I need to import the CSOM libraries?

Comment: Have a look at this for module import.  note this is for site collection but after you have imported the modules.  It should work. http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2016/07/28/office-365-switch-to-new-modern-ui-with-powershell-and-csom/